# Google analytics: Conversion funnel

Tags: google-analytics

How can I track how many macro-conversions (for example a free trial) has been a resoult of a micro conversion (for example e-book download)?
In other words, I would like to track the number of people who come to our site, download an e-book and later on convert to a free trial of our product.
I would like to see a funnel that shows us how many people move through each step. Also, I would like to segment that funnel by campaign source.
How can I do that in Google analytics?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:
Create a Goal.
Set the Goal Type to destination.
Put the URL for the thank you/confirmation page for the free trial as the destination. 
Enable Conversion funnel.
Put the URL for the Download E-book success/confirmation page as the 1st step.

Here is a pic of what I would do:

[image]